# Map stored procedure into the model generated by EF 4 as a model for MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is the thing I`ve added an EF automaticcaly generated class from the database as a model to my mvc application and everything is working great except one thing . When I add a stored procedure and function import to my model everything is added the way it should be but I get no intellisense for my stored procedure. Any idea? 
Everything works fine if im gonna just add an EF model to the root of my solution.But when my model is in Models folder of my MVC application it seems that it doesnt work !

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a valid error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try right-clicking on your entities .tt file and choosing "Run Custom Tool".

Comment: thnks a million it worked ;) . I`ve been searching for answer for more that 4 hours. could u explain What does this Run custom tool do ?And why its not getting mapped in Models folder ?

Comment: Honestly I wish I could :)  I'm constantly having to run it to update my Model and context.

Basically it runs the script (in the .tt file) that generates the code for your model.  For some reason it doesn't always trigger automatically when upadting your model and you have to manually run it.

I've gotten in the habit of doing it on all of the .tt files in the Model every time I update the Model.  If you added a new complex type (for instance) there is a different .tt file to run.